# When is crontab executed?

Tags: linux, cron, redhat

I have several crontab jobs that are executed every minute and I’m thinking on putting “@reboot” jobs. They are put and executed with root privileges.

So here’s what I want to know. Will these cronjobs run when system gets to login screen after rebooting? Will “@reboot” entries run after reboot without me getting logged into root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should run automatically as soon as the `cron` service gets started. The exact moment can vary depending on the cron implementation and your init system.